# esem.diagram() in R - remove rectangles from items in diagram

Tags: r, psych

I am performing ESEM with psych.
`esem.diagram` returns a graph in which the items overlap.
I would like to ask for some help with fixing the overlap or removing the rectangles please :)

[image]

My Code:

```
esem1 <- esem(modelESEM, varsX=c(1:33),varsY=c(34:41) ,nfX = 4, nfY = 1, fm = "minres", 
              rotate = "promax", plot = TRUE, cor = "cor", use = "pairwise")
esem.diagram(esem=esem1, cut=0.4)
```